# parameters wont pass into my scipy.optimize.minimize function when embedded in a def. They keep returning as 'undefined'

Tags: python-3.x, var, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Thanks for looking, I have taken advice and simplified the code as much as I can in order to isolate the malfunction.

The function used within minimize can't find my frequency or amplitude breakpoints. It seems to be related to embedding the getpaz() def with its minimize function within another definition. When I run the Getpaz() function with it's minimize code within the main loop, it runs. When I create a definition (such as a channel processing def) it fails.

The following code should run that duplicates the problem in Jupyter Notebooks as well as in compiled python 3.x in a command line. The problem is, the minimize function cannot find my referenced variables 'response' or 'frequencies', even though they are plainly there. I do not understand why the minimize function is failing. This showstopper has set me back three weeks; and I am at my wit's end in trying to figure it out.

If I take the definition paztest_fixed() and strip it's code out and place it into the executable loop, it runs. Does anyone have any insight into what's making it fail and how I can fix it? I really need a definition so that I can process multiple channels for a whole catalog of historical seismic stations!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal
import scipy.optimize


# Daniel Burk, Michigan State University


def pazto_freq_resp(freqs, zeros, poles, scale_fac):
    b, a = scipy.signal.ltisys.zpk2tf(zeros, poles, scale_fac)
    if not isinstance(a, np.ndarray) and a == 1.0:
        a = [1.0]
    return scipy.signal.freqs(b, a, freqs * 2 * np.pi)[1] 
            # list element 0 is frequencies
            # list element 1 is the complex amplitudes

def phasecalc(testresponse):  # Bring in a list of complex numbers and return the angle between 90 and 270 degrees
    testphase = []
    for t in testresponse:
        tp = np.arctan2(t.imag , t.real) * 180. / np.pi
        if tp > 90.:
            tp = tp-360.
        testphase.append(tp - 90.0) # adjust phase to better match what is seen in the real world calibrations
    return(testphase)


# This is the function definition that is used in the scipy.minimize function.
def minimize(_var):     # Uses data found in frequencies, and in response. 
                        # Make sure phase and response tables use the same subset of frequencies.
    p1r, p1i, p3r, p4r, p5r,z1r,z2r,z3r, scale_fac = _var
    new_resp = pazto_freq_resp(
        freqs=frequencies,
        zeros=np.array([0.0 + 0.0 * 1j,
                        0.0 + 0.0 * 1j,
                        z1r + 0.0 * 1j,
                        z2r + 0.0 * 1j,
                        z3r + 0.0 * 1j], dtype=np.complex128),                        
        poles=np.array([p1r + p1i * 1j,
                        p1r - p1i * 1j,
                        p3r + 0.0 * 1j,
                        p4r + 0.0 * 1j,
                        p5r + 0.0 * 1j], dtype=np.complex128),
        scale_fac=scale_fac)
    return ((np.abs(new_resp) - np.abs(response)) ** 2).sum()



def getpaz(frequencies,response,Phasedeg):

    evaluation = 1.0E+09 # For evaluating how close the solution is to the original curve
    paz = [] # The new poles and zeros for the channels

    for z in range(0,32): # iterate 32 times to find the solution that best describes the phase response.
        initial_x=[]
        X0=np.random.random(9)
        #                                Using the minimize function, find the poles & zeros solution that best describes
        #                                the instrument response as found in responses, on frequencies breakpoint "frequencies"
        out = scipy.optimize.minimize(
            fun=minimize,
            method="BFGS",
            x0=X0,
            options={"eps": 1e-10, "maxiter": 1e8})

        x = out.x
        new_poles = np.array([-abs(x[0]) + abs(x[1]) * 1j,
                              -abs(x[0]) - abs(x[1]) * 1j, 
                              -abs(x[2]) + 0.0 * 1j,
                              -abs(x[3]) + 0.0 * 1j,
                              -abs(x[4]) + 0.0 * 1j], 
                              dtype=np.complex128)    

        new_zeros = np.array([ 0.0 + 0.0 * 1j,
                               0.0 + 0.0 * 1j,
                              x[5] + 0.0 * 1j,
                              x[6] + 0.0 * 1j,
                              x[7] + 0.0 * 1j], dtype=np.complex128)
        new_scale_fac = x[8]
        #              Create the response curve that results from this theoretical new poles and zeroes solution
        inverted_response = pazto_freq_resp(freqs=frequencies, zeros=new_zeros, poles=new_poles,scale_fac=new_scale_fac)    
        inphase = phasecalc(inverted_response) # phase from inverted response, listed in degrees
        curvefit = np.sqrt(((np.array(Phasedeg) - np.array(inphase))**2).mean()) # rmse
        if (curvefit) < evaluation:
            final_iteration = z
            best_poles=new_poles
            best_zeros=new_zeros
            best_scale_fac=new_scale_fac
            print(f'Iteration # {z}: Phase misfit drops to {curvefit}')
            evaluation = curvefit
    return(best_poles,best_zeros,best_scale_fac,evaluation,z)

def paztest_fixed():
    #################################### test with def #################################
    Component = 'LM.NE8K.MHZ'
    Caldate   = '05/15/2019'
    #              Frequency breakpoints within the passband of the seismometer to simulate
    frequencies = np.array([0.05, 0.0571, 0.0667, 0.080, 0.111, 0.133, 0.167,    \
                   0.222, 0.250, 0.286, 0.333, 0.400, 0.500, 0.526,     \
                   0.555, 0.588, 0.625, 0.666, 0.714, 0.770, 0.833,     \
                   0.910, 1.000, 1.111, 1.250, 1.429, 1.667, 2.000,     \
                   3.000, 4.000, 5.000, 8.000])

    #               here are the gain values for the seismometer at the above frequencies
    response = np.array([3.00, 4.48, 7.11, 12.28, 32.81, 56.56, 110.00, 258.43,      \
            366.09, 542.60, 852.84, 1451.12, 2764.14, 3201.37, 3734.65, \
            4390.91, 5205.66, 6225.33, 7508.61, 9123.91, 11134.60,      \
            13556.01, 16267.16, 18911.45, 20951.61, 22004.53, 22120.93, \
            21630.53, 20132.44, 18990.64, 17947.77, 15053.22])

    #           phase delay of the light beam vs. ground motion in degrees at above frequencies
    Phasedeg = [-6.660, -7.714, -8.880, -10.800, -14.800, -18.000, -22.200, \
                -30.000, -33.300, -37.543, -44.400, -52.560, -66.600,       \
                -69.158, -73.800, -78.353, -83.475, -89.520, -96.429,       \
                -104.677, -114.600, -126.654, -140.760, -157.600, -175.500, \
                -193.886, -211.560, -228.024, -254.865, -269.640, -280.080, \
                -300.528]

    best_poles,best_zeros,best_scale_fac,evaluation,final_iteration = getpaz(frequencies,response,Phasedeg)

    print("\n========================================")
    print(f"Inverted values for {Component} on caldate of {Caldate}:")
    print("Poles =\n", best_poles)
    print("Zeros =\n", best_zeros)
    print("Scale_fac = ", best_scale_fac)
    print(f"Evaluated misfit of phase = {evaluation} on iteration # {final_iteration}\n")
    print("========================================")


##############################  RUN CODE AS A DEF ######################

paztest_fixed()
```

Comment: That is a lot of code to go through and a lot of undefined variables. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have revised the question and provided a complete code snippet that duplicates the problem. It fails when paztest_fixed() is run, but strip the guts out of that def and run it in main() and it'll run. Only, I need it to run in a def as I build the greater program. Anyone have any insight into what's going wrong?

Comment: Correction: I can't even run it in main().  I'm writing a severely disabled stripper program at this point, because my deadline is tomorrow. The conference where I am presenting this code is in a week. I've been pretty much sunk by this bug.

Comment: Anyway, I think by avoiding the use of definitions, and embedding everything in the main body, I think maybe I can work around it... It wont be pretty and there will be duplication but it might get me out of the frying pan for the short term...

Comment: Did my answer not work for you? Only two lines of your code needed changing for me to get the output

Comment: ooh! let me check. I've tried that path once but got lots of errors, but it's possible my syntax wasn't quite right....Ah, here it is: the order in which I placed the 'args' option was wrong so I abandoned that path. But this might just do it: The test code indeed works! Let me apply it to the bigger code... and Yes!!! This is VERY encouraging! I think you might have solved it! A simple fix to a HUGE, two-week show stopper. I only hope it 'stays' this simple... Thank you!

Comment: Your answer definitely did work! I am making great progress on the code now and the remaining pieces have almost fallen into place. I am quite happy tonight.

Comment: Glad I could help, consider voting for and accepting the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the scipy documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html), we see

> **scipy.optimize.minimize(fun, x0, args=(), method=None, jac=None, hess=None, hessp=None, bounds=None, constraints=(), tol=None, callback=None, options=None)[source]**

and

> **args : tuple, optional. Extra arguments passed to the objective function and its derivatives (fun, jac and hess functions).**

Your minimize function needs to somehow know what `frequencies` and `response` are. Modify your minimize function so that it takes those two parameters in, and then add an argument in your call to `minimize` to include those arguments. It should look something like this:

1. Changing `minimize` definition:

```py
def minimize(_var, frequencies, response):
    # Rest of your code
```

2. Adding these arguments to your call to minimize (inside the `getpaz` function)

```py
out = scipy.optimize.minimize(
            fun=minimize,
            args = (frequencies, response), # <--- This is what I added
            method="BFGS",
            x0=X0,
            options={"eps": 1e-10, "maxiter": 1e8})
```

These changes give me this output.

```
Iteration # 0: Phase misfit drops to 1.224353466864608

========================================
Inverted values for LM.NE8K.MHZ on caldate of 05/15/2019:
Poles =
 [ -3.13071301+6.04747984j  -3.13071301-6.04747984j
  -4.50400442+0.j         -32.91191804+0.j
 -52.80201143+0.j        ]
Zeros =
 [ 0.00000000e+00+0.j  0.00000000e+00+0.j -3.24109312e+01+0.j
  1.19677764e-04+0.j  6.81647031e+02+0.j]
Scale_fac =  1602.3460317044198
Evaluated misfit of phase = 1.224353466864608 on iteration # 31

========================================
```